# Using a list of all file names, output missing files names if not contained in folder (batch script)

Tags: batch, batch-file

I want to:

1. Compare filenames from `C:\folder\filelist.txt` to `C:\folder\filenames`.
2. Output missing files names from `C:\folder\filenames` to Missing.txt.

Code:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (C:\folder\filelist.txt) DO (
IF EXIST %%i (echo %%i>>C:\folder\filenames) 
ELSE echo %%i>>C:\folder\Missing.txt
```

My Missing.txt output is listing all the filenames contained in filelist.txt instead of listing only the filenames that are missing from `C:\folder\filenames`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is just to identify the missing files use NOT with EXIST.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (C:\folder\filelist.txt) DO (
  IF NOT EXIST "c:\folder\%%~i" (echo.Missing "%%~i">>C:\folder\missing.txt)
)
```